# IIS 7 how to customize the security model using c#

Tags: c#, iis-7, httpmodule

We have migrated a legacy streaming server to Wowza. As well as streaming on that server we need to have some mobile handsets have their delivery of mp4 files to be handled by IIS (7) HTTP straight download.

I need to replicate the security model that we had before based on our own key within the url parameters. (This I have done in Wowza also now). Nothing built-in in IIS would match our needs. So what I need to do is create a plugin for IIS that can see the URL of all incoming requests and either accept or deny them.

Can anyone point me into the right direction as to the API / plugin I should be interested in?

Comment: One the tags you've picked suggests a valid approach - have a custom httpmodule for this.

Comment: yes that tag may have been a clue! However from that I think it may be a httphandler rather a httpmodule based on an example I now can see thanks

Comment: No, not a httphandler, definitely a httpmodule. Specifically, a module has the `AuthorizeRequest` event you can hook into and there you validate an upcoming request. Depending on the outcome of the validation, the request can be blocked or you can even set up a principal for the request. Google more for "custom authentication httpmodule". There are so many good examples your question even doesn't need an answer.